# Hystrix metrics via JMX: how to get values before any command invocations?

Tags: java, metrics, hystrix

I'm using Hystrix 1.5.3 in Spring Boot application, and the metrics are published to JMX via `hystrix-codahale-metrics-publisher`. I also tried using `hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher` with the same exact result, so I'm not sure if the publisher implementation matters.

The problem is that there are no JMX MBeans/attributes visible until the corresponding `HystrixCommand` executes.

For example, if I have two `HystrixCommand`s - `Foo` & `Bar` and just started the app, the MBean with metrics won't appear at all. If the command `Foo` is executed, the MBeans and attributes appear, but only for `Foo`. What I want to achieve is having visible MBeans and attributes for both `Foo` and `Bar` immediately after application startup.

According to [Hystrix metrics wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring#hystrixrollingnumber), looks like the storage is really initialized with the command execution. I've also gone through [Hystrix issue tracker](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20metrics) and didn't find anyone who had problems with such behavior.

Is there a way to force exposing metrics for all existing `HystrixCommand`s? I don't have a lot of commands, so manually adding them to some registry and initializing with default values will probably be OK.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Damian0o unfortunately I had to manually initialize all metrics that I need, using e.g. `MetricRegistry.counter("some.metric")` or `MetricRegistry.timer("some.metric")`.